# desktop app (windows app) connect windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

is there a assembly or API to get isolated storage in windows phone using WPF or win form while connecting the windows phone device via USB?

please note the devise will be running offline so cannot use web service or WCF

thanks

Comment: If you're connected by USB, the phone uses your computer's internet service. Will the PC be offline too? Currently, there's no way to directly access your isolated storage via the USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this article on emulator automation](http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation). It includes details of adding and removing files from isolated storage and should also work on an actual device as well as the emulator.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for... However.. I got an error "Access Denied.. Make sure you have sufficient priveleges to access this resource" on line: "f.ReceiveFile(@"\Applications\Data\" + appID + @"\data\isolatedstore\foo.txt", @"\foo.txt");" while debugging it in VS2010.. any ideas?

Comment: guys any helps on this please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a supported activity. I too have been thinking about what to do when you want a desktop version with extended features and you want the two to share data.

I think the key here is to think about how Microsoft achieves this with email and calendaring. There's no shared filesystem, rather Outlook on the desktop and Outlook on the phone both function as clients for the same Exchange server.

At one point I considered running a webservice in a desktop app so that the phone app could push data to the desktop app, but that would be a very manual process. The common-server model will provide a much better UX.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact match to your situation, but a good tool is the [Windows Phone 7 IsolatedStorage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/).

[image]

The reason I say it may not be the best match is this note from the [documentation](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/documentation):

> The WP7 Isolated Storage Explorer
>   supports connections from the emulator
>   or actual devices. For applications
>   running on devices a data connection
>   must be enabled (WiFi or the mobile
>   data connection).

It's at least a great start and keeps you from having to do the heavy lifting. Is there any reason you have to be offline and check the contents of IsolatedStorage? If you elaborate on why you have that requirement, we might be able to offer some work arounds.